# Where i can get white colorscheme from gVim?

Tags: vim

Usually I like to use this theme:

[image: picture]

How I can get it in Vim?

Answer (score 1):

Vim's default colorscheme will look just like GVim's if you set your terminal emulator's background to white.

[image: default on white]

Comment: @gymshoot Make sure to accept the answer if it solves your issue.